# Get values by property name from an object at different levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, linq, object

I have an object in the below format and I need to get all values from the `Price` property at all levels of the object.

```
var o = {
    Id: 1,
    Price: 10,
    Attribute: {
        Id: 1,
        Price: 2,
        Modifier: {
            Id: 34,
            Price: 33
        }
    }
};
```

I was thinking of LinqToJS and `jquery.map()` methods but I'd like to get a method as generic as possible. I tried this but it only works at the first level:

```
var keys = $.map(o, function(value, key) {
    if (key == "Price") {
        return value;
    }
});
```

Comment: want price of all levels as an array? like `[10,2,33...]` ??

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive function which tests the type of name of the property and its type. If it's name is `Price`, add it to an array. If it's an object, recurse through that object to find a `Price` key. Try this:

```
function getPrices(obj, arr) {
    $.each(obj, function(k, v) {
        if (k == "Price")
            arr.push(v);
        else if (typeof(v) == 'object')
            getPrices(obj[k], arr);
    });
    return arr;
}

var prices = getPrices(o, []);
console.log(prices); // = [10, 2, 33]
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gvjnz1xf/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `$.map()` to do this very easily:

```js
var o = {
  Id: 1,
  Price: 10,
  Attribute: {
    Id: 1,
    Price: 2,
    Modifier: {
      Id: 34,
      Price: 33
    }
  }
};


var res = $.map(o, function mapper(obj, key) {
  return key === "Price" ? obj : $.map(obj, mapper)
});


document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

This works because of the odd feature jQuery's `$.map` has where if you return an Array from the callback, it gets flattened into the result.

Therefore we can recursively call `$.map` with the same function on anything that's not the `Price` key, and the array it returns will just get emptied into the final result.

You can avoid some calls if you check `typeof obj === "object"` if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `for..in` loop, recursion

```js
var o = {
    Id: 1,
    Price: 10,
    Attribute: {
        Id: 1,
        Price: 2,
        Modifier: {
            Id: 34,
            Price: 33
        }
    }
};

var res = [];

(function re(obj) {
for (var prop in obj) {
  if (prop === "Price") {
    res.push(obj[prop])
  } else {
    re(obj[prop])
  }
}
}(o));

console.log(res)
```